# getResponseHeader is empty

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile, odata

here is an **Android mobile application**, from which I'm making call to **SAP SERVER** . I came across a very strange problem.

I'm making a ajax call to server and getting data as expected.
but the problem is `c.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token")` returns `null`. But  I can see the response header in browser console and it is as per my expectation.
How to get the response header?

[image: Browser Console image]

```
var a = {};
    a = {
        // object that contains HTTP headers as name value pairs 
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password),
        "X-CSRF-Token" : "Fetch",        
    }, 
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: requestUri1,
        headers: a,
        success: function(a, b, c) {
            globalTocken = c.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token");
            alert(globalTocken);
        },
        statusCode: {
            401: function() {
                alert("User name and password is wrong");
            },
            403: function() {
                alert("error 403");
            }
        },
        error: function(a, b) {
            alert(b);
        }
    });
```

I have tried these ways also.

```
   OData.request    ({
             requestUri: requestUri1,
                   method: "GET",
                   headers:  {   
         "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa(user_name + ":" + pass_word),
                                      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                                      "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml",
                                      "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",       
                                      "X-CSRF-Token":"Fetch"
                       }           
                },
                 function (data, response)
                 {
                      var header_xcsrf_token = response.headers['x-csrf-token'];
                      //console.log(header_xcsrf_token);
                      alert(header_xcsrf_token);

                 },function(err) {
                    
                    //Error Callback:   
            
                    alert("Error occurred " + err.message  + err.response.statusText);
        
                });
```

Another way

```
var request = {
    headers : {
        // object that contains HTTP headers as name value pairs 
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa(user_name + ":" + pass_word),
        "X-CSRF-Token" : "Fetch",        
    },
    requestUri : requestUri1, // OData endpoint URI 
    method : "GET",
    datatype : "json",
};
OData
        .read(
                request,
                function(data,response) {
                    x_csrf_token = response.headers["X-CSRF-Token"];
                }, function(err) {
                    
                    //Error Callback:   
            
                    alert("Error occurred " + err.message  + err.response.statusText);

                });
    }
```

Comment: client and server are in the same domain?

Comment: No, because first 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.' ERROR was coming. Then I installed Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: extension in crome. Now I'm facing this error.

Comment: if you call getAllResponseHeaders() what is the result?

Comment: c.getAllResponseHeaders();
"Content-Type: application/atom+xml; type=feed;charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0

Comment: The haeder X-CSRF-Token seems not to be present. Are you sure the server sets the header in the response? If you call the api with postman what happen?

Comment: from postman - every time token is coming.

Comment: can you check if the browser sends the preflight request? i had a similar problem. I set my server in order to accept the OPTIONS method and  authentication headers. Read more on "CORS with authentication"

Answer (score 0):

I have done lot of R&D and reached to a conclusion that all of the three coding are correct problem is from server side, it is not generating Token everytime so I have saved token in local memory and using it until the new one will not get generate from server(I'm making call to server everytime). it is working for me.

```
function save_all(){ 
         var globalTocken,X_CSRF_Token,a = {};

    a.Authorization   = "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "password"), 
    a["X-CSRF-Token"] = "fetch", 
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        cache: !1,
        url: requestUri1,
        headers: a,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(a, b, c) {
        if(!c.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token")){
                globalTocken = localStorage.savedTocken;
                X_CSRF_Token = globalTocken;
        else{
            globalTocken = c.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token");
            localStorage.removeItem("savedTocken");
            localStorage.setItem("savedTocken",globalTocken);   
             X_CSRF_Token = globalTocken;

        }           
        },
        statusCode: {
            401: function() {
                alert("User name and password is wrong");
            },
            403: function() {
                alert("error 403");
            }
        },
        error: function(a, b) {
            alert(b);
        }
    });
```